# Show that the lines from the two ends of a parabola's latus rectum to the intersection of its directrix and axis, make a right angle

Tags: geometry

> Show that the lines joining the two ends of the latus rectum of the parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ and the intersection point of the directrix and the axis, are at right angles to each other.

(Solved)

Comment: Unlike a lot of other parabola problems, this is one you can almost just draw the answer to. What have you tried, and what was the difficulty?

Comment: I used (2a, ± 2a) as the ends of the latus rectum and thats where my problem was, I figured. It's now been solved. Sorry I shouldve rectified it by myself before posting for help

Comment: @user701763: If you've solve the problem, then you should post your solution as an answer so that we can upvote it. :)

Comment: Sure will do :)

Answer (score 1):

> ***Solution*** :  For the parabola y² = 4ax, the ends of the latus rectum must be (a, ± 2a). The intersection of directrix and the axis of the parabola is (-a, 0) which can obtained by solving the equations of directrix and axis. 
>   Now the product of the slopes of the line joining (-a, 0) and (a, ± 2a) yields -1, proving that those lines are perpendicular to each other